# How to print a message in Scilab console window?

Tags: scilab

I am using scilab 5.5.2 version. How can I print a message in the console window of Scilab? What is the function used for that?

Comment: `disp`: https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/disp.html. Example: `disp('Hello World');`

Answer (score 3):

You can use either the [disp](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/disp.html) or the mprintf functions. Example:

```
disp('Hello World')
```